# Table <tr> onclick with rel

Tags: html, database, html-table, onclick

I am using a plugin that requires rel=ibox (the ibox javascript plugin)

This works with no problem:

`<a href="test.php" rel="ibox" title="Test">Test</a>`

However, how would I implement this into this `<tr onclick>` function?  This is for a table and I want each row to use the ibox plugin.  Can this be done?  I've only seen examples using an `href` for each `<td>`

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href = 'view.php?id=<?=$objResult["id"];?>';">
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

`<tr onclick="iBox.show(document.getElementById('your_div_id').innerHTML)">`

or

`<tr onclick="iBox.showURL('url')">`